# Checking for whitespaces with RegEx

Tags: regex

I have strings that look like `some text - other text` and I need to delete everything before and including the hyphen `-` and the space after it

But do to typos I might have :
`some text -other text` or `some text- other text` or `some text-other text` or double spaces instead of single spaces

I am using RegEx `^.*\s+\-\s+` and this works for `some text - other text` with single or multiple spaces before and after the `-`

But for the other possibilities where the whitespace is missing, I have used two `or` so I have `^.*\s+\-\s+|.*\-\s|.*\-`

Is there a more concise patter that does not use multiple `or`s for this?

Thank you for any help on this

https://regex101.com/r/TNU7i6/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using an alternation with 3 patterns,  you might use a pattern to match all except the `-`, then match the `-` and optional whitespace chars.

```
^[^-]*-\s*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vaxF9Y/1)

If there should be a non whitespace char following, and a lookahead is supported:

```
^[^-]*-\s*(?=\S)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[^-]*-` Match 0+ times any char except `-`, then match `-`
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `(?=\S)` Positive lookahead, assert a non whitespace char to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QN4455/1)

**Note** that `\s` and the negated character class `[^-]` can also match a newline.

Comment: why don't you have to escape the `-` ? Whay is it not `^[^-]*\-\s*(?=\S)`

Comment: @xyz333 Because `-` is not a metacharacter, you don't have to escape it. Only if you put it in a character class and it is not the first or last character, then you have to escape it to prevent accidentaly matching a range.

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples, please try following.

```
^.*?\s+\S+\s?-\s*(.*)$
```

***OR***

```
^.*?\s+\S+\s*-\s*(.*)$
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/LAnrHE/1)

---

---

***2nd solution:*** You could use `\K` option too to forget matched regex part, in that case try:

```
^.*?\s+\S+\s?-\s*\K.*$
```

***OR***

```
^.*?\s+\S+\s*-\s*\K.*$
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/ohhONN/1)

***1st solution explanation:***

```
^.*?\s+  ##From starting of value matching till 1st occurrence of space(s).
\S+\s?   ##Matching 1 or more non-space occurrences followed by optional space here.
-\s*     ##Matching - followed by optional space.
(.*)$    ##Matching everything till last of value.
```

***2nd solution explanation:***

```
^.*?\s+  ##Matching everything till 1st space occurrence(s) from starting of value.
\S+\s?   ##Matching non spaces 1 or more occurrences followed by space optional.
-\s*\K   ##Matching - followed by spaces(0 or more occurrences) and \K will discard all previous matched values(so that we can match exact values as per output).
.*$      ##Matching everything after previously matched values(which is discarded by \K).
```

Comment: Thank you, I will study this one for my improvment